# cpp template specialization, error saying type of the argument 1 is T which depends on the parameter T

Tags: c++, template-specialization

```
line 1； template <class T, T t> struct C {}; // primary template
line 2:  template <class T> struct C<T, 1>; // error: type of the argument 1 is 
                                  // which depends on the parameter T
```

my understanding is that primary template accepts two template arguments which are same type. but in line 2, one parameter is unknown, the second one is int(1), so these two parameters can not be same type in certain cases.

but the error message saying "depend one..." according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization

how should I understand this case?

Another question is

```
template <class T, T t>
template <class T, T>
```

is there any difference in behaviour or anything else between these two

thank you for your help

Comment: For the second question, you just can't name the second parameter. From the perspective of the template "user" there's no difference. But please keep it to one question per question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ 17 Standard (17.5.5 Class template partial specializations)

> 8 Within the argument list of a class template partial specialization,
>   the following restrictions apply:
>
> (8.1) — The type of a template parameter corresponding to a
>   specialized non-type argument shall not be dependent on a parameter of
>   the specialization

As for these two template parameter lists

```
template <class T, T t>
template <class T, T>
```

then the only difference is that the identifier of the non-type template parameter in the second case is not specified. So within the template definition you can not refer it.

Comment: i still do not understand this restriction.In Primary template, two same template argument. In line 2, class T and 1(int) should be same type, so class T should be int which depends on 1(int). Is that violation？

Comment: @Athos In the partial template specialization the type of template parameter T is unknown. SO what does 1 as the second template argument mean?